# Ag grid: how to show drop-down in cell of grid

Tags: ag-grid-ng2

I am new to Ag grid for angular 2. I wanted to know that how i can populate a dropdown in a cell and on selecting a value. how i can know what value was selected. Please help, plunker would be great help.

Comment: any luck with that ?

Comment: yes, I already did that

Comment: and? Will should share the knowledge?

Comment: @JeanAlesi this can be achieved by a cell renderer and whenever any value selected. You can pass a context to the component.
For more information you can check for cell renderer as a component

Answer (score 0):

You can use cellRenderer like below:

```
  {
    headerName: 'ABC',
    field: 'ABC,
    width: 135,
    cellRendererFramework: CellDropdown,
    cellRendererParams: {
      pass the CellDropdown Props here
    }
  }
```

In the CellDropdown custom component, you will get setValue as a prop from ag-grid. Using which you can set the entered value in the table cell